# Generate *.mdb file with Visual Studio 2017 for PCL

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, mono, portable-class-library

I want to create a NuGet Package of an PCL that Targets .NET, UWP, Android (Xamarin), iOS (Xamarin) and so on (for Example lets say Profile111).

When I reference the project in an Android app Visual Studio 2017 creates a *.mdb file which the mono debugger uses to enable step through code.

Now I wan't to get the same result with an Solution/Project that just contains the PCL code.

What I got when I compile my sample.csproj with VS2017 is

```
sample.dll
sample.pdb
```

whats missing:

```
sample.dll.mdb
```

At the end I want to be able to create a nuspec file like this one:
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/167/files

Every hint is welcome.

Tank you
Alex

Comment: Did you set the debugging information to full in the project advanced build settings?

Comment: @Alex Witkowski, Like this case here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37739/pdb2mdb-converter-throws-error-saying-dll-mdb-file-does-not-exist-when-building, it seems that it was related to the pdb2mdb which used to generated to the mdb file. Also like this extension which also has the pdb2mdb integration for Visual Studio: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonEgli.MonoTools

Comment: Check the actual build output if the for `csc` compiler command - it should contain `/debug:full` switch (not `portable`). Then you should be able to use `pdb2mdb` tool from Mono like @JackZhai-MSFT mentioned above